# Linq : Grouping rows and returning them in anonymous collections

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have a table containing PlanID & Location as two columns, with "many to one" relationship.
That is, one planID can have multiple locations.

Sample data could be as follows :

```
PlanID   Location
------   --------
111      Blr
111      Bom
222      Chn
333      Hyd
111      Bhu
333      Ctc
```

I am attempting to group them by unique PlanIDs & return anonymous collection (say UniquePlans) like below :

```
PlanID   Location
------   --------
111      Blr
111      Bom
111      Bhu


PlanID   Location
------   --------
333      Hyd    
333      Ctc

PlanID   Location
------   --------
222      Chn
```

Once I have the result collection ready, I need to do some operation for each item like :

```
 foreach (var planID in uniquePlans)
    {
        foreach (var loc in PlanLocation)
        {
            //TODO : WCF call to fetch some detail based on planID & PlanLocation
            // pDetail = GetPlanDetails(planID, PlanLocation);
        }
    }
```

I am using Entity Framework to fetch the data from SQL server DB & using below code I am able to find all unique PlanIDs.

```
var uniquePlanCollections = myEntities.PlanDetails.Select(p => p.PlanID).Distinct();
```

But after that I am not getting any clue how to group them (using linq or lambda exp) so that I can use them inside my foreach loops.

I ve also attempted something like below, but its not working...

```
var test = from r in myEntities.PlanDetails
                       group r by new
                       {
                           r.PlanID,
                           r.Location

                       } into g
                       select new
                       {
                           PlanID= g.Key.PlanID,   //Can I use distinct here? 
                           Location = g.Key.Location
                       };
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ToLookup:

```
var lookup = myEntities.PlanDetails.ToLookup(pd => pd.PlanID, pd => pd.Location);
foreach (var grouping in lookup)
{
    var planId = grouping.Key;
    foreach (var location in grouping)
    {
        // do something with planId and location here
    }
}
```

Also, if the Location property points to another table, be sure to add `.Include(pd => pd.Location)` before ToLookup so that all the information will be loaded in a single query.

Comment: I am not sure how you are making sure that it will be grouped in to three different unique groups / collections. Can you please explain that part of code, if its doing so?

Comment: [This is](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/24/c.net-little-wonders-the-tolookup-linq-extension-method.aspx) a very good article for the `ToLookup()` method. It will group your collection in to three different colletions (based on the arguments passed to the method)

Comment: But when I tested the above code I found the grouping is happening correctly, but in each group only the first location is getting repeated multiple times, instead of unique Locations (for eg: for PlanID : 333 group, the location "Hyd" is getting repeated twice, instead of "Hyd" & "CTC".]

Comment: I'm getting the right result as  you can see from my img: http://imgur.com/OXXNWiI

Comment: Using Lookup is little costlier, as its not having deferred execution,  can I go for GroupBy instead to achieve the similar result?